# logstash log4j input plugin over ssl

Tags: ssl, log4j, logstash

The log4j input plugin does not natively support SSL,

is there a suggested way to securely fetch directly from a log4j socket appender into logstash that I am missing? it seems very strange that this does not exist anywhere.

thanks

Comment: Note that the reasons as to why this isn't currently supported are [discussed here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2341).